# Are there unsolvable 8 puzzles just like 15 puzzles

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

I am developing a 15 puzzle sliding puzzle game using JavaScript. As half of the combinations in a 15 puzzle is unsolvable I use the formula in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/15Puzzle.html to check the solvability. 
I am currently adding the option to switch to 8 puzzle (3x3).
Are there unsolvable combinations in 8 puzzle too? If so can I use the same formula for it too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, half of the configurations of a **n-puzzle** game are *unsolvable* as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle) and [here](http://icpc.baylor.edu/history/icpc99/Regionals/SCUSA98/results/eight.html).
Also you can apply the same criterion: the number of inversions of the permutation shall be even.

Comment: The second link you provided doesn't work.